# EF Core annotation for client side generated values

Tags: ef-code-first, data-annotations, ef-core-3.1

I'd like to set my code-first class (EF Core 3.1) to have generated values with value generators (`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ValueGeneration.ValueGenerator`). It's important to me that the values are generated on the client side and not on the database side. Also, I would like to use an annotation instead of the fluent API because I need to use derived types; something like this:

```cs
public class typeX
{
  [Key]
  [some-annotation?] // This is where I want to add my annotation
  public string MyKey { get; set; }

  [some-other-annotation?] // This is where I want to add my annotation
  public string OtherData { get; set; }
}

public class derivedA : typeX
{
}

public class derivedB : typeX
{
}
```

I'd like to annotate `MyKey` and `OtherData` so they will use generators (e.g. `GuidValueGenerator`, `MyCustomValueGenerator`). I think I know how to use the *fluent API* for that (although most examples are for database side generation), but I can't find a way to use annotations. Is this possible? I'd like to generate values on creation in some cases and on creation+update in others.

Thanks

Comment: No, it's not possible. Many things in EF Core are available only through Fluent API (have no corresponding data annotations).

Comment: Oh, bummer. The Fluent API doesn't play very well with inheritance.